# ARIMA Parameter selection from ACF/PACF plots

Tags: r, arima

So I have a time series which I cannot share with you all, but I have a few questions about the proper proceedings to fit the correct ARIMA model for my data.

I have successfully written a loop to determine what degree of differencing needs to be done (parameter d in I(d))

Question:

To determine p and q, I am looking at ACF and PACF plots of my data. However, I am wondering if I should be using a deseasonalized transformation of my time series (trend plus random error, but no seasonality component which could be added back later) or my original time series. I obtained the deseasonal data using the decompose function in R (is stl() significantly better?).

With the original time seriees, my acf plot looks like:

[image: ACF Plot]

[image: PACF Plot]

There is some definite seasonality at play here from the ACF plot. Does that mean I need to identify nonzero seasonal parameters in my final model if I need to use this data? How do I choose seasonal P and Q in this case?

With the deseasonalized data, here are what the plots look like:

[image: ACF Plot]
[image: PACF Plot]

Not sure how to interpret the deseasonal PACF/ACF plots other than the fact that the spike at lag 6 on the ACF plot indicates p might be 6?

Just learned ARIMA this summer and would appreciate the help from anyone who knows the subject well how to choose the optimal parameters based on what I've shown. Looking forward to a good discourse :)

Comment: Is there a reason you distrust `auto.arima` or is this more of a learning exercise?

Comment: This is more of a learning exercise. Also auto.arima on this particular data is an ARIMA(0,0,0) model which I am not very impressed with as an answer.

Comment: Have you tried it without the shortcuts?  `auto.arima(ts, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE)`.  It is designed to make some assumptions to run faster but can sometimes choose a sub-par model.

Comment: NO I Have not, I will play around with those thanks